# AIR for iOS app is automatically closed when another app is opened

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

It appears that my app is automatically closed once another app has been opened. Is this a feature of the operating system or am I doing something incorrectly?

**Result app kept running in background (state remembered):**
1. Open AIR for iOS application.
2. Double-tap home to enter app switcher.
3. Select the same AIR for iOS application.

**Result app is restarted (state reset):**
1. Open AIR for iOS application.
2. Double-tap home to enter app switcher.
3. Select different app.
4. Double-tap home to enter app switcher.
5. Select the same AIR for iOS application.

Tested using AIR 16 and iPhone 5 running iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: Also, iOS will quit any apps that are open (suspended) when it likes to. Another app may need the RAM, for instance. So you can never be sure your app will not be closed some time after you leave it.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED:**

I needed to set this to false in my application.xml:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<false/>
```

For more info scroll to "Exiting instead of pausing":
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html